# ldap_add: Invalid syntax

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to add an Active Directory record via PHP. The CN contains a apostrophe (single quote), and I'm trying to find the correct way to escape it.

Things I've tried:

```
$dn = "CN=Conan O'Brien,OU=test,DC=test";
ldap_add($link_id, $dn, $attributes);
ldap_add($link_id, addslashes($dn), $attributes);
ldap_add($link_id, str_replace("'", "\\39", $dn), $attributes);
```

Each one gives the same error. Obviously, I have verified this code works without an apostrophe in the DN.

```
ldap_add(): Add: Invalid syntax
```

Comment: I assume that both plain old \' and \\' have been tried without success?

Comment: Normally in LDAP it is `\' ` that does the needed escaping.

Comment: addslashes converts the ' to a \'. I have verified this using printf. So yes I've tried that; that's my middle case. I also just tried \\' without success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two apostrophes instead of one. It's because one escapes the other.

The \ escaping is used for special characters ("," ";" "=" etc...) and hexadecimal-encoded characters, which is used when the value has no string representation.